# How to avoid rounding numbers having more than 16 digit precision in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Objective is to read data from json file using node js. Observed that numbers with more than 16 digit precision are rounded.
Code:

```
var raw = fs.readFileSync(file);
JSON.parse(raw);
```

Result:

```
0.59190000000000009 is rounded to 0.5919000000000001

4647.3424257097241 to 4647.342425709725

6441579.5333300168 to 6441579.533330017
```

Comment: This is not JSON.parse, but the float number type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: You'll get the same result if you just type `var foo = 0.59190000000000009;` it has nothing to do with JSON. It's just the limit of JS numeric precision.

Comment: Json parse is abiding by the rules of floating point numbers, which is built into the js engine. You can perhaps think about using a json library that parses big int. https://github.com/sidorares/json-bigint. But this doesnt handle decimals. So, perhaps you could also try structuring your json with the numbers as strings, then parsing the strings as BigDecimal via a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignumber.js

Comment: Voting to re-open. The proposed duplicate doesn't answer the question of "how to avoid" this, it only answers why this happens.